# adding label number to first and last observation

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created the following graph. I would like to annotate the first value and the last value for each of the line created in the graph. The value would be annotated for each line just before the line and at its end

How to?

```
data = {'Time':['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2' , '1', '2'], 'Country':['Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy',  'Russia', 'Russia',  'Russia', 'Russia' ,  'Russia', 'Russia',  'Russia', 'Russia'], 'Score':[20, 21, 14, 15, 19, 18, 5, 9, 5, 8, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 8]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Score", hue="Country",  data=df)
```

Comment: You would need to elaborate more on what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, see if it works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details on what you exactly want you can use the axes object returned by [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and then use the `text` method of the axes object.

In the following I calculate the mean 'Score' for each country at 'Time' = 1 and then then add this as text to the graph. You can customise this as needed:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Score", hue="Country",  data=df)

means = df.groupby(['Country','Time']).mean()

times = ['1', '2']
x_positions = [0.02, 0.9]

for country in df['Country'].unique():
    for time, xpos in zip(times, x_positions):
        mean = means.loc[(country, time)].values
        ax.text(xpos, mean-1.1, mean[0])
```

[image: example_text_to_axis]

Comment: This is great, I would also like to have it for Time = 2, how to do it? Also, this is just a dummy dataset and I have more than just two time periods - how can I create a general code for this?

Comment: You can just add a second call to the text method (I have/ will change to show this).

Comment: There you go added - its not very general, but hopefully the additional verbosity will help you understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks again, the only problem is that I have numerous time periods (10). When i run your code, I get the following error: KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [columns]'

Comment: I managed! it worked! I changed  times = ['0', '10'] to times = [0, 10]

Comment: Great, happy to help. Yep you could easily extend this by adding different times or defining a list of times (i.e. `times = np.arange(1,11)`)

Comment: can you explain what times and position do? I notice that when I change my column of interest (from Score to another column that has smaller values (usually less than 4) the labels disappear.

Comment: Positions is simply the positions of the text on the x axis (varying from 0 to 1), to determine the y axis position I use the position of the 'mean' so when you change the column from score you are changing the y axis position

Comment: makes totally sense, is there a way I can assign the same color of the line to the text?

Comment: Yep, look at the [ax.text](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) It takes kwargs of Text